# django-admin.py doesn't work properly

Tags: python, django, powershell

I can use `django-admin.py startproject foo` and it works fine, however now when I try for instance `django-admin.py shell` or `django-admin.py help`, nothing happens.

By nothing happens, I mean (for the `django-admin.py shell` example) the console doesn't open up the shell command like `manage.py` would, but instead will pop up and immediately close a new window as it does when I double-click a python file. There isn't any error message, the console just doesn't output anything.

Hopefully what I am trying to say makes sense. It's kind of hard for me to explain. I used to be able to use the `django-admin.py shell` command, so I don't know what happened.

Anyone know whats going on? Thanks in advance, and if I need to try to clarify something feel free to ask and I will try.

Comment: Re: "... will pop up and immediately close a new window as it does when I double-click a python file." Are you running Windows? That might be a useful clue.

Comment: sorry, I use powershell on Windows 7

Comment: sounds like you have some errors in your setup. Try open a command prompt window and cd to your scripts directory and do your "python manage.py command" instead of doing the shortcut. If your command fail it should fail you your error message.

Comment: Ryan, "python manage.py" works fine. I am having problems with the "django-admin.py" command.

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade your version of Python/Django? Sometimes there's a compatibility issues and you have to uninstall the previous version.

Comment: Nope. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

When the window pops-up and then disappears that means an error is occurring inside of the action being called, but no error message is being returned for display in the command line. In my case, I was trying to run manage.py (and any command) and it required MySQL-python to be installed first.